# How to track cusom property of user like device in Google Analytics v4 for Android?

Tags: android, google-analytics, analytics

For example, every user has a device.
I can view segmentation (pie) of users by device.

How can I make the same for custom user property? For example, I want to know which percent of my users have Facebook app installed and which don't.

There's custom dimensions, but it bounds to specific event, I think it is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Custom Dimensions can hold any kind of information (String) you want. But you are bound to information you can access: does your app know, if the facebook app is installed? I'm not much into Android Java but I guess this information is not available.
However there is no better way to send custom user information then Custom Dimensions. This is exactly the use case.

Comment: Info is available. Thanks for answer.